# Filter dataframe rows using a list of datetime.date objects

Tags: python, pandas

**Issue:**

I am trying to filter my dataframe rows using a list of `datetime.date` objects. I get `ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 175033 vs 33`

**Data:**

```
type(third_friday_lst)
list

type(third_friday_lst[0])
datetime.date

third_friday_lst

[datetime.date(2013, 1, 18),
 datetime.date(2013, 2, 15),
 datetime.date(2013, 3, 15),
 datetime.date(2013, 4, 19),
 datetime.date(2013, 5, 17),
 datetime.date(2013, 6, 21),
 datetime.date(2013, 7, 19),
 datetime.date(2013, 8, 16),
 datetime.date(2013, 9, 20),
 datetime.date(2013, 10, 18),
 datetime.date(2013, 11, 15)]
```

**What I have tried:**

If I use the following code I get the desired output but only when I specify the first item in the list with `third_friday_lst[0]`:

```
data[data['dt-date'] == third_friday_lst[0]]

                       Date         Time    Open    High    Low   Last Volume   dt-date
Timestamp                               
2013-01-18 08:00:00 2013/1/18   08:00:00    7875.5  7876.0  7867.5  7870.5 1059 2013-01-18
2013-01-18 08:05:00 2013/1/18   08:05:00    7871.0  7878.5  7870.5  7877.5  511 2013-01-18
2013-01-18 08:10:00 2013/1/18   08:10:00    7877.0  7879.0  7875.5  7875.5  226 2013-01-18
2013-01-18 08:15:00 2013/1/18   08:15:00    7875.5  7878.0  7874.5  7876.0  162 2013-01-18
```

**Desired output:**

I would like to filter rows in `data` using `third_friday_lst` without using the list index`[0]` as I want all the dates contained in the list.  I would prefer not to use the `['dt-date']` column but if this is required it is fine.

thanks

Comment: `data[data['dt-date'].isin(third_friday_lst)]`?

Comment: That's what I would say. ^^^

Comment: Thanks that did it.  If you add the answer I will accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
data[data['dt-date'].isin(third_friday_lst)]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, I mentioned in the post that I didn't want to use the `['dt-date']` column:

```
data[data.index.to_series().dt.date.isin(third_friday_lst)]
```

Comment: Looks like you can also do it in a slightly simpler fashion too: `data[data.index.isin(third_friday_lst)]`

Comment: @EHB actually this is not working as it'll only filter exact match between the index datetimes and the list of dates hence only get rows at midnight